# Suppress Terminal Window When Running Python Build from Stream Deck

Tags: python-3.x, python-packaging, streamdeck

I have a python project that I have built into a distributable package that can be installed with pip. The package was intended to be used alongside a Stream Deck to give users the ability to "open" the program using the open action and have control over devices on their LAN (think turning on and off lights)

The package works as expected when it is run directly from the command line, however when the program is run from a Stream Deck using the "open" action a terminal window pops up and stays open even after the program has finished executing.

I have tried looking for various methods to suppress this behavior, and I understand that since my program is a cli tool it makes sense for the packaged program to open a terminal window. However since the terminal window does not open when the .py file is run as opposed to running the built package I am hoping there is a way to suppress this behavior.

If I run a .sh script using the open action from a stream deck that points to the python program a terminal window does not open, however this creates an extra step for users when configuring their stream deck and complicates passing arguments to my original program.

I am working with MacOS. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I am happy to provide any additional information, I am relatively new to actually packaging my projects rather than using them on my local machine, so I apologize if this isn't possible and just the nature of running a packaged python project.